# Configure scala project sdk for idea

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

I know there is already questions about it on stackoverflow, but none of them helped me answer my question. I just downloaded idea with the scala plugin and created a new scala project. I got the error `no jdk for this project`.

After looking on internet I understood that I need to give it the java sdk for it to run. `readlink -f $(which java)` gave me the java jdk location (`/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java`) but adding it to the option like shown below didn't help.

How to configure the project sdk for an sbt project ?

[image: My project configuration]

Comment: "but adding it to the option like shown below didn't help." Why not? What happened when you did this?

Comment: You're in completely the wrong settings menu here. Those are editor wide settings, and that setting isn't for setting a jdk but simply a setting for which jvm to run sbt with (which should be left at the default "use project sdk" in most situations).

You need to go to the project settings menu, which is another menu entirely. You can get there with the shortcut ctrl+alt+shift+s on Windows and Linux. Also, the project sdk setting should point at the sdk directory, not the bin directory within the sdk.

Answer (score 1):

To set the **JDK**, go to the Project Structure dialog in the "Project" tab. If you haven't set up a JDK yet, click "New..." and choose the home directory. Note that this needs to be a JDK ([download from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.htmll) or [install via apt](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04)), not the JVM you are using in your screenshot.

[image: Project Structure]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project Structure and do what I marked on the screen
[image: How to add scala SDK to IntelliJ IDEA]

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't helped me.